# UML / API : How to model a RESTful API

Tags: rest, api, symfony, uml, api-platform.com

I need to create a UML class diagram and a use case diagram for a RESTFul API that I developed using API Platform and Symfony 3.2 (backend) and Ionic 2 (frontend).
But i dont exactly know how to describe the structure of my backend API through the class diagram.

If anyone has any idea or could be of any help, i'd truly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Your question is way to basic (or too broad depending on how you look at it). That kind of question calls for "read a book" or "visit a class".

Comment: @ThomasKilian Thank you for response. My question is i want to know how to represent the components of my API in a class diagram. Sequence diagrams are easier to design since you can describe the interactions between the API and the system. But I dunno how to get around with the class diagram, how to represent the structure of my API.
Many thanks for your help

Comment: What did you try so far? Creating a class diagram is  far more easy than constructing SDs.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I tried creating a few classes but it didnt make any sense to me. I also thought class diagrams were easier but i couldnt get around since the topic is different than the usual. I'm currently trying this https://github.com/nrekretep/pikturr which looks like an awesome tool that transforms the structure of my restful API (through Swagger) into a class Diagram. If you thought of any suggestions that would help, i'd appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: Just letting a machine draw "something" is not really a documentation, I think. You need to understand the concept of classes before creating any SD. You need to put the horse before the carriage.

Comment: Once again thanks for your help. I dont think you quite understood my question (Or I didnt ask it clearly) but i've found the solution. Thank you.

Comment: On StackOverflow it's a common practice to put the solution in an answer (_to be useful also for other users_) :-).

Comment: Indeed. If you answer your own question we all could learn.

Comment: @gp_sflover I just did, I'm a little new to this heh. Thank you ! :)

Comment: Well done! ;-) To the next!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So the solution to my problem was a bit of all of the following :

**https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/design-implement-restful-web-services/**  : 
I concluded from this that, although it's difficult to model a restful api in a class diagram (since it's basically just a bunch of methods), consider the classes like "Resources", add the methods (basically the HTTP methods), and the paths to each resource.

This was also of huge help:

- https://firstinfinity.wordpress.com/modeling_rest_web_services/

Another (simpler) way was to use tools like Pikturr, which transform your Swagger into a UML diagram.

Softwares for designing REST APIs :

- Visual Paradigm
- IBM Rational Software Architect

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

Api Platform automatically generates a Swagger documentation for your API at the URL `http://localhost/docs.json`.

You can generate an UML diagram from the Swagger documentation using tools like https://github.com/nrekretep/pikturr

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply @Kévin Dunglas , i will try this out, looks simple and effective. Life saver !

Comment: I see pikturr works only if you have a Java executable. On a quest to find one compatible with my .Net application

Answer (score 1):

It is too late, but this is another approach.

If you do not know about [Visual Paradigm](https://www.visual-paradigm.com) you can give it a try.

You can use this content, [Visual Paradigm - How to Design REST API with UML?](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/276/3420/85154_modelingrest.html). It is easy, to represent your REST API. I prefer [Postman Collections](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/collections/creating-collections/) BTW (it is not UML).

But if you are doing some other kinds UML artifacts for documentation purposes. Well, Visual Paradigm gives you a bunch of UML diagrams to do that. So you keep that ecosystem of diagrams.

See ya.

Comment: I came across Visual Paradigm in my quest to find the perfect way to model REST APIs and continued looking because I'm licensed to use draw.io and MS Visio where I normally design and maintain models. Adding a new tool to the mix will complicate things abit but it's the perfect representation. I tried to replicate it but it just doesn't work as well as it does in Visual Paradigm. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

The real answer for the question is to use an **UML Component Diagram**, since its very purpose is to model architectures based on services. Check this link for more info: https://diagramasuml.com/componentes/